# Error substituting/referencing string constants

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use a string constant from a different typescript file as a key in a map type.

Here's a simple example:

`src/common/model-constants.ts`

```
export default class Constants {
  public static readonly KEY_PREFIX: string = "x";
}
```

`src/models/prop.ts`

```
export interface AProps {
  readonly key: {
    [key: string]: string;
  };
}
```

`src/index.ts`

```
import Constants from "./common/model-constants";
import AProps from "./models/prop";

const prop: AProps = {
  a: "1"
};

const prop2: AProps = {
  Constants.KEY_PREFIX : "2"
}

const prop3: AProps.key = {};

prop3[Constants.KEY_PREFIX] = "3";
```

`prop` and `prop3` work, but `prop2` does not compile with

```
/src/index.ts: Unexpected token (12:4)

  10 | var prop2 = {
  11 |     Constants: model_constants_1.default,
> 12 |     : .KEY_PREFIX, "2": 
     |     ^
  13 | };
  14 | var prop3 = {};
  15 | prop3[model_constants_1.default.KEY_PREFIX] = "3";
```

Here's the same thing in codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-bartik-2bbqx

Why does referencing the string type constant directly in the map literal not work? Why do I see `model_constants_1.default` in the error console?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your intent is here, but I took the time to fix your code as best I could... : [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-paper-2z334?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: @spender Thank you for taking the time and fixing the errors, but I think I commented out the part that was giving the error in the question. Could you uncomment lines 8,9 and 10 from `index.ts` from your sandbox link to see what my question is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) and is written like this:

```js
const prop2: AProps = {
  [Constants.KEY_PREFIX] : "2"
}
```

Also consider either to change `AProps` declaration or to add `key` property to your objects:

```typescript
class Constants {
  public static readonly KEY_PREFIX: string = "x";
}

interface AProps {
  readonly key: {
    [key: string]: string;
  };
}

const prop: AProps = {
  key: {
    a: "1"
  }
};

const prop2: AProps = {
  key: {
    [Constants.KEY_PREFIX] : "2"
  }
}

const prop3: AProps = { key: {} };

prop3.key[Constants.KEY_PREFIX] = "3";
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKknpW)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a computed value as object key, you need to use angle brackets *[]*

```
const prop2: AProps = {
[ Constants.KEY_PREFIX] : "2" 

}
```